# Field 'id' expected a number but got <QueryDict:

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

When I Submit Form I Got This Errors Field 'id' expected a number but got  
Why i got this errors ? What's wrong in my code :(

View:

```
def employee_list(request):
    if request.POST and request.FILES:
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.user = RiverTimeUser.objects.create_user(
                username=request.POST.get('name'),
                pin=int(request.POST.get('pin')),
                password=request.POST.get('pin')
            )
            data.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
                                'New Employee Added Successfuly')
    context = {
        'object_list': Employee.objects.filter(department__institute=request.user.institute),
        'form': EmployeeForm(request.user.institute.id)
    }
    return render(request, 'employee.html', context=context)
```

Form:

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['create', 'update', 'admin', 'user']
        widgets = {
            'date_of_birth': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }

    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
        if RiverTimeUser.objects.filter(username=name).count() > 0:
            raise ValidationError('This Employe Username is already in use.')
        return name

    def __init__(self, institute, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.fields['designation'].queryset = Designation.objects.filter(institute_id=institute)
        self.fields['department'].queryset = Department.objects.filter(institute_id=institute)
```

### Edited Full Traceback Info

I could not find out the exact wrong

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1772, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)

The above exception (int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict') was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\New folder\atms\custom\methods.py", line 24, in wrap
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\New folder\atms\user_maintenance\views.py", line 22, in employee_list
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\New folder\atms\user_maintenance\forms.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.fields['designation'].queryset = Designation.objects.filter(institute=institute)
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1350, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1311, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1165, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line 115, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\riaju\Documents\atms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(

Exception Type: TypeError at /employee/
Exception Value: Field 'id' expected a number but got <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['vfO31XU2Y8x9MBzfUZ7rnq4widBlrt2uu6aF63ZorSW9DO6Rv8gjNE72SIN0YY1p'], 'name': ['Training'], 'designation': ['1'], 'department': ['1'], 'phone': ['12345'], 'date_of_birth': ['2020-12-31'], 'card_number': ['124'], 'pin': ['1234']}>.
```

Comment: Have you checked if the data got saved in database?

Comment: Please show us the entire error trace. It's not clear which line of code is actually causing this error. Note that `int(request.POST.get('pin'))` is not safe, if there is no pin or if the pin doesn't map to integer this will raise an error (not the error you're seeing)

Comment: @Ejaz Yeah, I Checked Database no data saved after submit ..!

Comment: please post your model,it would be helpful

Comment: Show your `EmployeeForm`. It looks as if you changed the `__init__` method, therefore `form = EmployeeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)` isn't working.

Comment: @Alasdair have you any idea how can i solve this..?

Comment: add your EmployeeForm

Comment: @Harun-Ur-Rashid vai  here is all related codes https://pastebin.com/QxqV8ytK

Comment: @Alasdair when i wan to add code in questions i got this error in ```It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.```

Comment: OK, I've added it to the question to you. You might have been able to avoid that error if you posted less code (your models weren't required) and if you added a sentence or two to describe what you are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in the `__init__` method. You have made the first argument `institute`, therefore you need to pass the institute for GET and POST requests.

```
def employee_list(request):
    if request.POST and request.FILES:
        form = EmployeeForm(request.user.institute, request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Secondly, you need to pass `*args` and `**kwargs` when you call `super().__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, institute, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.fields['designation'].queryset = Designation.objects.filter(institute_id=institute)
    self.fields['department'].queryset = Department.objects.filter(institute_id=institute)
```

An alternative approach is to pop `institute` from the kwargs instead. This means you don't change the signature of the `__init__` method.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    institute = kwargs.pop('institute')
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.fields['designation'].queryset = Designation.objects.filter(institute_id=institute)
    self.fields['department'].queryset = Department.objects.filter(institute_id=institute)
```

If you do this, then change the way you instantiate the form to:

```
def employee_list(request):
    if request.POST and request.FILES:
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST, request.FILES, institute=request.user.institute)
        ...
    context = {
        'object_list': Employee.objects.filter(department__institute=request.user.institute),
        'form': EmployeeForm(institute=request.user.institute.id)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Alasdair :) Solved

Comment: This is the perfect answer. 
Still works after 3 years :)

Answer (score 0):

Your actual error happens in form `__init__` method:

```
self.fields['designation'].queryset = Designation.objects.filter(institute=institute)
```

, where `institute` seems to be PK or FK field and you're passing an queryset instead in filter.

Comment: Thanks but it's not working..
**views.py**
```context = {
        'form': EmployeeForm(request.user.institute.id)
    }```

**forms.py**
```self.fields['designation'].queryset = Designation.objects.filter(institute_id=institute)```

Comment: @RiajulKashem is there any pending migrations you have to run?

Comment: @Ejaz there is no pending migrations

Comment: @Charnel sure, take a look 

```def __init__(self, institute, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.fields['designation'].queryset = Designation.objects.filter(institute_id=institute)
        self.fields['department'].queryset = Department.objects.filter(institute_id=institute)```

for better reading [pastebean](https://pastebin.com/X2jB0sUL)